# dropdown-menu doesn't work inside the div or dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I try to use "dropdown-menu", when it's outside div, it's works.

But when it's inside the div or added dynamically, it's not works.

Sample on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahma/n156kjyd/)

The code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v3dboy.ir/previews/html/frest/frest/assets/vendor/css/rtl/core.css">

<button data-bs-toggle="dropdown">drop down</button>
<div>
  <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">drop down in div</button>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu A</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu B</a>
</div>

<div id="dynamicBox">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the [mcve] here using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .dropdown-menu is not wrapped inside the div with the dropdown button.

```
<div>
 <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">drop down in div</button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu A</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu B</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And for the runnable snippit

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v3dboy.ir/previews/html/frest/frest/assets/vendor/css/rtl/core.css">
  
<div>
<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">drop down in div</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu A</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu B</a>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```